# Skype for business via Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, microphone, skype-for-business

I'm using skype for business via remote desktop.

In order to make audio calls I use these settings:

[image]

It works fine for the firsts minutes of the call. But then seems my Microphone stop working.

Both computers are Windows 10 version 1809 and are connected with gigabit Ethernet connection with no firewall.

I don't have any connection issue, or lag or packet dropped.

I need every time to restart the call.

Connection seems fine. Event viewer has not alerts or warnings.

Where can I investigate for problems?